# Visual studio code is unable to recognize my Android Smartphone

Tags: java, flutter

I'm unable to use my android smartphone to flutter in visual studio code.
Here is what I get if I want to solve the problem:

[image]

I updated the android sdk from android studio to the last version and I installed java jdk 21 and executed the command flutter doctor --android-licenses but I get the same errors.

I expect to use my Android smartphone and build apps using flutter

Answer (score 0):

Not seems a problem of visual code. What you show is the (Powershell) terminal. If you run this commands in a PS outside vscode, you will get the same result.

Seems a problem with the JDK that you are using or pointing at the time of execute. There is a clash of Java class binary version 55 vs 61.

I think you are using JDK-11(55) when you need (at least) JDK-17(61).

Comment: So it seems like the command flutter doctor doesn't recognize my java jdk version because I downloaded and installed the version 21 and I set my JAVAHOME environment variable to the jdk 21 installation folder.
How can I tell flutter to use the right java version if it doesn't consider the JAVAHOME variable?

Comment: To clarify, it should be `JAVA_HOME`. Probably also add to `PATH`where the java/javac executable is located. NB I'ḿ not a flutter user.

Comment: Yes, I mistakenly mistyped that, but I set it correctly, and I also had the PATH set correctly to %JAVA_HOME%\bin. However, I still encounter the same errors.